# Using fermat's little theorem and the chinese remainder theorem?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So I'm trying to find $9^{65}\pmod{77}$.

What I've done:

I used Fermat's little theorem and separated them into $9^{65}\pmod7$ and $9^{65}\pmod{11}$, where I got the remainders to be $4$ and $1$ respectively. Now, I have no idea what to do from this point. What is the best way to combine both to get the final answer?

Comment: now find a number that is between 1 and 76 inclusive, and is both 4mod7 and 1 mod 11. that is your answer.

Comment: how do i do that without checking every number?

Comment: nvm i got it, thanks!

Comment: Apply Easy CRT in the dupe to solve $\,x\equiv 4\pmod{7},\ x\equiv 1\pmod{11}\ $ There are also many other answers here showing how to apply CRT.

Answer (score 0):

I will show how to solve the congruences in a simple way that can be used for smaller values:

$$\begin{align}
x&\equiv4 \pmod 7\tag1
\\x &\equiv 1 \pmod {11}\tag2
\end{align}$$

Now note that from $(1)$, $x=7a+4$, where $a$ is an integer. From $(2)$, $x \equiv 1 \pmod {11}$ so:

$$\begin{align}
7a+4 &\equiv 1 \pmod {11}
\\7a &\equiv 8 \pmod {11}
\\7a &\equiv 63 \pmod {11}
\\a &\equiv 9 \pmod {11}
\end{align}$$
So from the above congruence, $a=11b+9$ where $b$ is an integer. Therefore, $$x=7a+4 = 7(11b+9)+4 = 77b+67$$
Because $b$ is an integer, we can deduce that $$x \equiv 67 \pmod {77}$$

Comment: cant i just use the extended euclidien algo and find 11x+7y = 1

Comment: yes that is true. that can be a strategy you can use as well. either way, it will require you to test some values

Answer (score 0):

Use the extended Euclidean algorithm:
$11x+7y=1$ , find $x = 2 , y = -3 $.

$9^{65}$ = $ (7y)+4(11x$) mod 77 
Basic plug in
$9^{65}$ = 67